# Flutter Error "not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a call to a class in a plugin to get a list of adresses, when I click on one I would like to show it on my `TypeAheadField` plugin. I can do all but actually show the selected text in the texfield of TypeAheadField. Here is my code for it

```
class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
 TextEditingController dropOffTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

TypeAheadWidget usage

```
TypeAheadField(
    textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
       ..............
    onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
        print(suggestion);
        dropOffTextEditingController.text =
            suggestion;
    }),
```

Now the class in the plugin where the list for TypeAhead is coming from

```
import 'geo_point.dart';

class Address {
  final String? postcode;
  final String? name;
  final String? street;
  final String? city;
  final String? state;
  final String? country;

  Address({
    this.postcode,
    this.street,
    this.city,
    this.name,
    this.state,
    this.country,
  });

  Address.fromPhotonAPI(Map data)
      : this.postcode = data["postcode"],
        this.name = data["name"],
        this.street = data["street"],
        this.city = data["city"],
        this.state = data["state"],
        this.country = data["country"];

  @override
  String toString() {
    String addr = "";
    if (name != null && name!.isNotEmpty) {
      addr = addr + "$name,";
    }
    if (street != null && street!.isNotEmpty) {
      addr = addr + "$street,";
    }
    if (postcode != null && postcode!.isNotEmpty) {
      addr = addr + "$postcode,";
    }
    if (city != null && city!.isNotEmpty) {
      addr = addr + "$city,";
    }
    if (state != null && state!.isNotEmpty) {
      addr = addr + "$state,";
    }
    if (country != null && country!.isNotEmpty) {
      addr = addr + "$country";
    }

    return addr;
  }
}

class SearchInfo {
  final GeoPoint? point;
  final Address? address;

  SearchInfo({
    this.point,
    this.address,
  });

  SearchInfo.fromPhotonAPI(Map data)
      : this.point = GeoPoint(
            latitude: data["geometry"]["coordinates"][1],
            longitude: data["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]),
        this.address = Address.fromPhotonAPI(data["properties"]);
}
```

The error on the console

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'SearchInfo' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

How can I edit my code without affecting the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error comes from this line

```
 dropOffTextEditingController.text =
            suggestion;
```

That's what we need to do :

```
 dropOffTextEditingController.text =
            (suggestion as SearchInfo)
                .address
                .name;
```

Comment: Oh shit! Would you care to explain the reason as well? I know I am trying to access the class directly as a string which didn't make sense..

Comment: Yes indeed you are trying to assign the value of the object directly to a string type hence the error that challenges you to say that the **SearchInfo** type is not a subtype of the string type ..... What should not be missed is the fact that the **text** property of a **TextEditingController** is a string so you cannot assign it to a **SearchInfo** object.